# C - Concatenar char (Não é STRCAT)

Tags: c

Tenho 2 variáveis: `char x[100]` e `char c;`

A primeiro instante, precisei armazenar `c` dentro de `x`. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
x[0] = c;
```

Dentro do meu programa, depois do executado anteriormente, a variável `c` muda de valor. Então eu preciso concatenar o valor de `c` junto ao `x` que já foi preenchido. Tentei fazer assim:

```
x[strlen(x +1)] = c;
```

mas não resolveu.

Usar StrCat não resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está aqui `strlen(x +1)`, o correto seria `strlen(x) + 1`.

Ficando

```
x[strlen(x)+1] = c;
```

Dependendo do seu código você nem precisa **somar** 1, exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAMANHO 100

int main()
{
    char x[TAMANHO];
    memset(&x, '\0', sizeof(char)*TAMANHO);
    char c = 'a';
    x[strlen(x)] = c; // strlen(x) retorna 0 porque está vazio
    c = 'b';
    x[strlen(x)] = c; // strlen(x) retorna 1 porque já possui 1 elemento

    printf("%s", x);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Saída

> ab

### [Ideone Exemplo](http://ideone.com/mB3DvQ)

Alterações sugeridas pelo <kbd>[ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25930/ctgpi)</kbd> e <kbd>[jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/500/jsbueno)</kbd>.

Comment: Voce rodou esse exemplo? Esa ciente que se ele funcionou foi por acaso, nao é? A lignuaem C não especifica que após uma declaração `char x[100];` o conteúdo das 100 posições reservadas para x é zero - (o seu compilador pode ae fazer isso "de favor" - -mas o conteúdo é indefinido. O que significa que star o caractere na posição [0]  não limita a string a [1] caratcere de comprimento - só se o caractere na posição [1]   for 0.

Comment: Rodei sim @jsbueno e no compilador que uso (online) funcionou exatamente como mostrado, se você fizer `char x[100] = ""` já inicializa tudo com `0` também, não?

Comment: Não sou expert em `C`, apenas sei o que vi na faculdade e brincando.

Comment: Entaou eu sugiro que arrume a resposta - pelo menos remova o exemplo errado, se nao vai tentar rodar ele -  a sua resposta para a pergunta está certa (tirar o "+1" de dentro do argumento do strlen) - mas o exemplo tem que ser ou arrumado, ou removido - nçao é só codigo que nao compila, é codigo com erros de conceito, que roda, e se for usado por outros uma porta aberta para falhas de segurança

Comment: Não é exatamente verdade que é um “acidente” o código funcionar — a memória que você recebe do sistema operacional sempre vem zerada (pra evitar vazamento de informação entre processos), então essa primeira alocação na `main()` sempre vai, sim, ser zerada. Mas eu concordo que isso é um caso de borda muito pesado — melhor fazer `memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x))` ou mover `x` pra escopo global (aí sim é 100% garantido que o vetor vem zerado).

Comment: @ctgPi Eu alterei o código, da uma conferida :)